# Does aws transfer utility(iOS) provides any provision for initializing shared identifier property for share extension?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension, swift2, awss3transferutility

I am getting this `AWSDomainError =-995` error when I upload image to S3.

Now I am solving this by adding the group in pod file in which case I have to unlock it.

Is there any configuration method to expose the property?